# MS Access - Multiple Queries shared Criteria in time stamp date range

Tags: date-range, ms-access-2016, criteriaquery

*MS Access* 2016,

I have Multiple queries - approximately 120 - that are gathering temp history based on date criteria that I currently update manually for each query - `>=#8/1/2021#` And `<#9/1/2021#` - for the month of August 2021.

> *What would be the best solution to update this in one place so all queries could refer to that one date range?*

Sample Query: (Usually 43 parameter points)

```
SELECT 
    History1HourAverage.TimeStamp, 
    History1HourAverage.Parameter001, 
    History1HourAverage.Value001, 
    History1HourAverage.Parameter002, 
    History1HourAverage.Value002, 
    History1HourAverage.Parameter003, 
    History1HourAverage.Value003, 
    History1HourAverage.Parameter004, 
    History1HourAverage.Value004
FROM History1HourAverage
WHERE 
    (
        (
            ***(History1HourAverage.TimeStamp)>=#8/1/2021#
            AND (History1HourAverage.TimeStamp)<#9/1/2021#
        )*** 
        AND ((History1HourAverage.Parameter001)="10S8MApp.nvoSpaceTemp") 
        AND ((History1HourAverage.Parameter002)="10S9MApp.nvoSpaceTemp") 
        AND ((History1HourAverage.Parameter003)="10S10MApp.nvoSpaceTemp") 
        AND ((History1HourAverage.Parameter004)="10S11MApp.nvoSpaceTemp")
    );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

Either

Add a table called DateRange with two fields, StartDate and EndDate. Enter one record in that table with the date range that you want to use for your queries. Edit each of your queries and include the DateRange table. Set the criteria for the query to `WHERE History1HourAverage.TimeStamp >= DateRange.StartDate And History1HourAverage.TimeStamp < DateRange.EndDate`

Alternatively

Create a VBA module with two functions

```
Public Function StartDate() As Date
    StartDate = #8/1/2021#
End Function

Public Function EndDate() As Date
    EndDate = #9/1/2021#
End Function
```

Set your query criteria for the query to `WHERE History1HourAverage.TimeStamp >= StartDate() And History1HourAverage.TimeStamp < EndDate()`

When you want to use a different date range you either (1) edit the data in DateRange table, or (2) edit your functions to return the new dates.